# Как сделать непрерывное изменение backround-position на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Знаю, как запустить анимацию из точки А точку В так сказать, но не знаю, как зациклить.
Ниже подготовил небольшой кусочек кода:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg) top left/30%;
  animation: bg 2s cubic-bezier(0, -0.02, 1, 0.99);
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position: left -100px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: делать два бэкграунда.. один распологается с точки 0 до конца ширины экрана, второй с точки ширины экрана и далее.... дальше менять transform translate обоих слоев.... когда первый уйдет за пределы экрана - присваиваем ему координату начала опять же за пределами экрана, как до этого было у второго слоя.....и так вот повторяем бесконечно

Comment: только вот непонятно, как это сделать, как привязаться ко второму фону да и вообще почему именно 2 а если я паттерн на фон поставил, и у меня их штук 30 в ширину помещается.

Comment: Что значит "привязаться ко второму фону" ? так вам нужно не сделать аля скроллер? может я не понял вопроса тогда..... может как-то изобразите что имеете в виду, что хотите и причем тут 30 штук в ширину

Comment: исправил код, вот нужно так, только непрерывно и на js

Comment: Добавьте свойству animation значение **infinite**.

Comment: если я добавлю, javascript из css не получится, и этот стиль не все браузеры поддерживают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все самому делать приходится)) не совсем ровно но подогнать можно либо картинку либо смещение под нее

```js
 setInterval(function bgmove() {
   $(".bg").animate({
     backgroundPositionY: 235
   }, {
     duration: 2200,
     easing: 'linear'
   });
   $(".bg").animate({
     backgroundPositionY: 0
   }, 0);
 }, 1);
```

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg) top left/30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg"></div>
```